# How to put text labels relative to axes in DS9?

Tags: python, label, astronomy, ds9

I'm using pyds9 as a wrapper to DS9 and I want to put text labels on my images with positions relative to the axes and not the coordinates. This way, the labels won't get messed up no matter what zoom I apply to the image.

Currently I am only able to put text in specified positions:

```
d.set('regions','fk5; text %s,%s #text="TEXT" color=black'%(ra,dec))
```

I expected to just change the fk5 for other command and a (x,y) position from 0 to 1 but so far I haven't found anything.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. You can use one of the coordinate systems listed in http://ds9.si.edu/doc/ref/region.html but they are all linked to the data.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, they are all linked to the data. Maybe there is an option to get the current edges values, calculate the range, and then I could multiply it by a fraction and add that to the left edge value.